# Implementing a Multi-task Scheduler and Executer using Boost Coroutines

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, boost, c++14

I'm searching for a way to use Boost Stackfull Coroutines as a multitask executioner in one single core, instead of using threads. I'm accustomed to develop Python code using the [*asyncio* module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and I would like to replicate the same behaviour using Boost Coroutines (Boost.Coroutine2 if possible).

My search at Google returned [some old Boost documentation](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/multitasking.html), explaining how I could do it using the Boost.Coroutine lib.
For some reason that I not aware of, [the current Boost.Coroutine documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) is not equal and does not contain any information that could relate to the old one.

Is there a way for me to use Boost.Coroutines in the same way I use the Python asynchronous Coroutines?

Comment: You might want to add Python tag to attract some Python crowd :)

Comment: Don't know if that is a good idea, but added anyway.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/executioner

Comment: Sorry! Bad choice of words from my part! 
What I meant was, a task Scheduler and Executor!

Answer (score 0):

I like using coroutines with Boost.Asio, since the latter even has [some integration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html) with the former.

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

// ...

boost::asio::spawn(io_service, [&] (boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
    // here, the asynchronous operations causes the coroutine to yield
    std::size_t bytes = socker.async_read_some(buffer, yield);
    // do some other stuff
});

io_service.run();
```

Boost.Asio has its own [full example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp).

The `io_service` will work as an executor, and `spawn` provides a clear way to do all this using coroutines.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I wasn't able to extend their example with coroutines that suspended their execution when waiting for futures. I also could not find an example or a way to do this.

Comment: @Claymore Good point. Unfortunatelly, it seems that we'll have to wait for Concurrency TS and Network TS to be able to do something like this out of the box. You can check out asio upstream, probably it has some futures support.